# How does the callback to the servers `request event` work in node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use a curried fn with a closure as a callback to the servers [request event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_request).

It works the first time a client makes a request (the html is sent and diplayed) but the second time the page is blank. Does node erase the closure after calling the cb once?

```
// server.js
var pype = function(self, arr, errorHandler, cb) {
  var i = 0,
  req,
  res,
  run = function() {
    arr[i].call(self, req, res, next);
  },
  next = function(err) {
    if (err && errorHandler) {
      return errorHandler.call(self, err, req, res);
    }
    i++
    if (i < arr.length) {
      return run();
    } else if (cb) {
      return cb.call(self, req, res);
    }
  }

  return function(request, response) {
    req = request;
    res = response;
    run();
  }
};

var http = require("http”);
var server = http.createServer();
var errorhandler = function(err, req, res) {
  res.end(err);
},
var finalHandler = function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  res.end(req.html);
};
var requestHandler = pype(null, [pens, gits, concat, index, sort, html, finalHandler], errorhandler);

// this works only once
server.on('request', requestHandler);

// this works for multiple calls
server.on('request', function(req, res){
  var requestHandler = pype(null, [pens, gits, concat, index, sort, html, finalHandler], errorhandler);
  requestHandler(req, res);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason why you aren't just making `run()` accept `request` and `response`? Relying on closure too much makes unreadable code.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha You're right on the readability. This is only an experiment. I don't think passing `req` and `res` to `run` would work though. They are needed in the body of `next` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node doesn't erase any closure.

I looks to me like you never reset `i` back to `0` when you are done with a request or starting a new request.  Because the closure retains all its state indefinitely, when the 2nd request comes in, `i` will point beyond the end of the array and you will never call any of the functions in the array.

You can reset `i`back to `0` either when you're doing with a request or at the beginning of a new request.

Change from this:

```
  return function(request, response) {
    req = request;
    res = response;
    run();
  }
```

to this:

```
  return function(request, response) {
    req = request;
    res = response;
    i = 0;
    run();
  }
```

to fix that specific issue, but you have other issues too (see below).

---

It appears this structure has other problems though.  Because you're creating only a single closure and then reusing it for all requests, whenever your first request goes async to process something and a second request arrives during that time, you will wipe out the closure variables of the first request and the two will collide.   This scheme of a single permanent closure is an untenable design for any server ever meant to handle more than one request at a time.

Your 2nd attempt that works just fine is a much better way to do things because you create a new independent closure for each request which will not have the race condition issue when multiple requests are in flight at the same time.

---

I must say, I really don't think the curried style is needed here at all.  You don't want to create a lasting closure that persists indefinitely (you need a new one for each request).  And, it makes your code a lot harder to understand and follow.

---

It seems much simpler to me without the currying:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();

function handleRequest(ctx, req, res, handlers) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var i = 0;

        function next(err) {
            if (err) {
                reject({err, req, res, ctx});
            } else {
                run();
            }
        }

        function run() {
            if (i < handlers.length) {
                handlers[i++].call(ctx, req, res, next);
            } else {
                resolve({req, res, ctx});
            }
        }
        run();
    }
}

function errorhandler(info) {
  info.res.end(info.err);
}

function finalHandler(info) {
  info.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  info.res.end(req.html);
}


server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    handleRequest(null, req, res, [pens, gits, concat, index, sort, html]).then(finalHandler, errorHandler);
});
```

Comment: Hi @jfriend00! Those damn incrementors. Always forget to reset them Good catch! You're right about the cyrring. Not needed at all. Just an experiment but not particularly readable. I was just trying to save a few lines by passing the requestHandler to the emit event instead of the body of the callback but as you pointed out this will clash on multiple simultaneous requests.TIL! Thanks a bunch. Really well explained. You should consider teaching! :D